# Summation rule index

Tags: sequences-and-series

In the simplification shown below, The index are changed but when i follow the index change rule, i cant find the same final answer.

$$\sum^{n-1}_{i=0} \frac{n}{n-i}=n\sum^{n}_{i=1} \frac{1}{i}$$

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Write it as

$$\sum^{n-1}_{i=0} \frac{n}{n-i}= \frac{n}{n} + \frac{n}{n-1} + \dots + \frac{n}{1}$$

Read from the end to the beginning.

$$\frac{n}{1} + \frac{n}{2} + \dots + \frac{n}{n} = n \Big(\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \dots + \frac{1}{n}\Big) = n\sum^{n}_{i=1} \frac{1}{i}$$

Comment: Thnaks @MonkeyKing
But can you explain more. I am still struggling.

Comment: Sorry I made typo at the first.

Answer (score 2):

Let $k=n-i$.

- When $i=0$, you have $k=n$.
- When $i=n-1$, you have $k=1$.

So your sum is as follows:

$$\begin{equation}\begin{split}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\dfrac{n}{n-i}&=\sum_{k=n}^{1}\dfrac{n}{k},\\&=n\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k}.\end{split}\end{equation}$$

Since you start the sum from $n$ to $1$ or from $1$ to $n$ is the same thing. Finally you can change the index $k$ to the index $i$.